# How to create C++ executables for flashing ROMs?

Tags: android, c++

I want to create C++ executables to flash ROMs over ADB on android phones, can anyone help me on this?
I have a basic knowledge of C++ but cannot understand from where I should start
The logic is
Initialize header files-->Initialize ADB service-->Start ADB shell-->Flash the .img files using flash_image binary--> ADB reboot

Can anyone give me a simple example for flashing boot image?
I m unaware what header files should I include, which compiler should I use.
created a new thread as I didn't find anything regarding this

Thank you

Comment: image flashing is done by the adb, you just need to open a pipe to the adb executable, feed it commands and watch the output

Comment: Yep...I have flashed boot.img, recovery.img images couple of times using ADB but want to create a C++ executable for the same
Can u give me example to flash a boot image using C++?
That example will explain me a lot :)
is it possible to flash system.img using ADB?
Which compiler to use?

Answer (score 1):

**adb** has nothing to do with flashing ROMs, adb is the debugger interface, which requires system up and running on your phone. And trying to reflash the ROM image with fully running system is like performing a heart surgery without an anaesthetic.

There are two basic ways of reflashing of ROM images correctly:

1. update.zip
2. fastboot

The former one is when you copy/download your ROM image as **update.zip** to the sdcard and then use recovery to update the system. This usually involves users pushing some buttons and powering phone off and on back again. This is the best method, because the update file is already safely stored on the sdcard, can be checked and verified, and the chance of bricking the phone is slim to none.

The second one is when you connect your phone to the PC, switch it to fastboot mode with 'adb reboot bootloader' (or switching off/on and holding some buttons), and then use **fastboot** to perform ROM update magic. Problem is, when using fastboot you need a very reliable USB connection. Any communication error and the phone is bricked. This is why I don't use and don't recommend fastboot method to reflash ROMs.

If you don't mind bricking your phone using fastboot method, the C++ program would be quite simple.

1. unpack ROM image somewhere (if you have it packed inside the program)
2. issue exec() or system() calls to run 'adb reboot bootloader' and then 'fastboot flash*' commands, then, finally 'fastboot reboot'
3. if you have done everything correctly (catch and process the output of adb and fastboot to check the results), your device will get reflashed and rebooted.

Finally, I'd like to stress again, reflashing ROMs with fastboot is quite dangerous, and I'd recommend to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Thank you
But I preferred ADB because not all phones have fastboot, do they?
Some of them have download mode.
Can you please give me a example, I m a newbie to C++ have a very basic knowledge
I will be interested in example in flashing boot image maybe

Comment: Secondly, why not flash system.img while system is ON?
As after flashing the system and passing adb reboot command phone will reboot and everything will be normal.
Maybe during flashing phone will die(not die but may cause blackscreen) but ADB bridge would be still ON, won't it?
I have flashed boot, recovery images via ADB but wanted to create a 1 click C++ program :)

Comment: Yeah I won't be taking risk of using fastboot even if phone has the fastboot support

Comment: How I flash images via ADB is
adb shell
$su
#flash_image recovery /sdcard/recovery.img
reboot recovery

Comment: Simply put, you cannot flash system.img while running Android for the same reason you cannot replace engine while driving a car: most probably it just breaks. 'flash_image recovery' replaces just the recovery image, very small part of the system, which is used to get system running, and lays dormant the rest of the time. ROM image usually consists of system (90%), boot (4%), radio (4%), recovery (2%) and maybe something else (percentage is approximate). You will not be able to replace anything except recovery with adb.

Comment: Ohk!! Can u mention program code for flashing recovery image in C++?

Comment: sorry, I don't know any. probably, because of the two reasons: 1) reflashing heavily relies on human interaction to observe what happens on the phone/make corrections/push buttons and 2) nobody would use C++ where simple command script would probably suffice